# It can happen that the norm 1 of a matrix and the infinite norm are different?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-norms

I have practiced some exercises with these two norms and in all of them I had the same result, until I tried with

$\begin{pmatrix}
5 & -3 & 2 \\
4 & 8 & -4 \\
2 & 6 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

$A_\infty =\frac{128}{9}$
$A_1 =\frac{119}{9}$

And the results were different, what makes me think I did something wrong (although I already reverb like 10 times).
So It can happen that the norm 1 of a matrix and the infinite norm are different?
Thanks :)

Comment: Infinite Norm is maximum absolute row sum. For one-norm it is column sum. How you are calculating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can happen:
$$A=
\begin{pmatrix}
5 & -3 & 2 \\
4 & 8 & -4 \\
2 & 6 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

In this case,

$\displaystyle\Vert A\Vert_1=\max\{5+4+2;|-3|+8+6;2+|-4|+|-1|\}=17$

and

$\Vert A\Vert_\infty=\max\{5+|-3|+2;4+8+|-4|;2+6+|-1|\}=16$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can happen, though I would check the answer again, since $\|A\|_1$ is simply the maximum absolute column sum and $\|A\|_\infty$ is the absolute row sum and I expect them to be integer for your question.